# Retrieve list of options name that changed using WordPress Customizer

Tags: wordpress, themes

is there any way that I can get options name (ID) and value just those options that get a modification using WordPress Customizer before getting saved.

I know there is a hook "customize_save_after" fires after Customize settings have been saved, maybe there's a global array containing all list of changed options ID.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank You!